# SSL client certificates and PHP: Apache compatible information with nginx

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I have a PHP login module that's based on SSL client certificates. It works well with Apache. Now I'm trying to figure out how to port it to nginx as well.

Using Apache it is very convenient to access the cert's content using the many environment variables set. The mail address will be in `$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email']` for example.

I've found the nginx variable `$ssl_client_s_dn` which I can pass to PHP via `fastcgi_param`. However, I will get the whole `DN` string.

- Do I have to parse the provided `DN` string on my own or are there better ways?
- If I have to parse it, which specification can I use to get the format right?
- Does nginx provide the same string as Apache does for `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx uses OpenSSL's `X509_NAME_oneline()` function to generate the string. The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_NAME_print_ex.html) of this function states the following:

> The functions `X509_NAME_oneline()` and `X509_NAME_print()` are legacy functions which produce a non standard output form, they don't handle multi character fields and have various quirks and inconsistencies. Their use is strongly discouraged in new applications.

Apache 2.2 uses the same function for `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN`. Since version 2.3.11, Apache HTTPD uses a [RFC 2253](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt) compatible format by default.

So to answer my own questions:

- > Do I have to parse the provided DN string on my own or are there
  >   better ways?

  The `$ssl_client_s_dn` variable is the only information nginx provides. As an 
  alternative, the raw certificate data is availabe too. However, this would possibly 
  lead to performance issue since nginx would have to copy the whole certificate for each 
  call.
- > If I have to parse it, which specification can I use to get the format
  >   right?

  The string is formated as `X509_NAME_oneline()` is implemented. It looks like parsing
  this string can't be done in a bulletproof way.
- > Does nginx provide the same string as Apache does for `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN`?

  Apache prior to 2.3.11 does, later versions use the RFC 2253 format by default. However, they can be configured to use the legacy format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map directive like

```
 map  $ssl_client_s_dn  $ssl_client_s_dn_cn {
     default           "";
    ~/CN=(?<CN>[^/]+) $CN;
};
```

Then you can use $ssl_client_s_dn_cn variable.  Similarly use a regex for email.

Comment: This answer should be somewhere in official Nginx documentation.